Why does changing selected value change selected item to null in c#
cmbOrganizacionaJedinica.ValueMember = "Id";
cmbOrganizacionaJedinica.DisplayMember = "Naziv";
cmbOrganizacionaJedinica.DataSource = vratiOJ();
Debug.WriteLine(cmbOrganizacionaJedinica.SelectedValue);
Debug.WriteLine(((OrganizacionaJedinica)cmbOrganizacionaJedinica.SelectedItem).Naziv);
cmbOrganizacionaJedinica.SelectedValue = 1;
Debug.WriteLine(((OrganizacionaJedinica)cmbOrganizacionaJedinica.SelectedItem).Naziv);

I get the SelectedValue with the first WriteLine, which is 1, but when i set it to 1 again it gives me an error because the selectedItem is now null

I found the reason. Id was long so cmbOrganizacionaJedinica.SelectedValue = (long)1; works

"Naked" numbers in code are often problematic. There are suffixes you can use - for your case `SelecteValue = 1L;"
